# Required to build docker image for already installed airflow on server machine

Tags: python, docker, image, containers, airflow

Required to install every time airflow on different machines, hence deploying to docker so that image can be shared across various machines. Assumed all the server machines are preinstalled with python 3.7.5 and required python package.

Below is my "Dockerfile" command

```
FROM apache/airflow:1.10.9
RUN mkdir -p /app/server/HOBS-DataPipeline/dags
RUN mkdir -p /app/server/HOBS-DataPipeline/logs
RUN mkdir -p /app/server/HOBS-DataPipeline/config
RUN mkdir -p /app/server/HOBS-DataPipeline/plugins
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash airflow
RUN chown -R airflow:airflow /app
COPY airflow.cfg /app/server/HOBS-DataPipeline/airflow.cfg
USER airflow
WORKDIR /home/airflow
```

Command used to build docker image

```
docker build -t docker/airflow:1.10.9a .

# Error in building image
Sending build context to Docker daemon   38.4kB
Step 1/11 : FROM apache/airflow:1.10.9
manifest for apache/airflow:1.10.9 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Please assist.
Thanks in advance

**Working environment details provided below**

Python 3.7.5

airflow version v1.10.9

**OS: Ubuntu**

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Release:        18.04

**Client: Docker Engine - Community**

Version:           20.10.12

API version:       1.41

Built:             Mon Dec 13 11:45:27 2021

OS/Arch:           linux/amd64

**Server: Docker Engine - Community**

Engine:

Version:          20.10.12

API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)

Go version:       go1.16.12

Built:            Mon Dec 13 11:43:36 2021

OS/Arch:          linux/amd64

Answer (score 0):

There are no 1.10.9 images of Airflow. They started to be published from 1.10.10.

Btw. You know that 1.10.* is already End of Lifr for almost 1.5 and version you try to install contains for sure security vulnerabilities and has plenty of bugs fixed since?

You know you should upgrade to Airflow 2 NOW ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please find the reason.
We have developed a handful of DAGs using airflow 1.10, and there are some basic syntax changes wrt airflow 2.x, which we are in the process of conversion. We have planned to release the airflow using docker with DAGs in interest of saving installation time and the environments we using to build docker is restricted to internet. So pulling images and necessary packages from internet is not possible. So required to build image on the installed version of airflow.

Comment: That does not change the fact that officil docker images for 1.10.9 do not exist

Comment: The request post was to get assistance in converting an existing application into docker image. Being airflow older version stated in the code used above, the context shifted.

Comment: `FROM apache/airflow:1.10.9` was the first line of wht the user wanted to do. This is will never work because the image does not exist. The easiest way to make it works is to migrate. The fact that less than few percent of the users (from latest survey) uses Airflow 1.10 and almost no-one there uses 1.10.9, it's highly unlikely the users will get a better answer than "migrate" @lakksv . It's just common sense.